# "Unable to connect to web server" and issues with localhost ports

Tags: blazor, localhost, port, blazor-webassembly, launch

When I initially made my  Blazor WebAssembly solution, a few months ago, I didn't tick an authentication option in the Blazor template on Visual Studio, so I thought I could fix that just by making a new solution and copying in all of authentication aspects into the original. (Could a .NET update could be causing my issue?)

Somehow, that caused my app to, as soon as it's built and ran, stop and Visual Studio throws the error "Unable to connect to web server 'Solution.Server'."
It is also worth mentioning that app.UseIdentityServer throws an exception when the app is started in debug mode, but I think that's a whole other error, don't know.

I tried googling it to no avail, but the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/webapplication?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:%7E:text=Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20web%20server%20%27AppName%27) did mention the exact error stating that it was caused by a difference between the ports specified in the localhost paths of the launchSettings.json documents and the port-specifying app.Run, but I can't find any port specified app.Run and am wondering if this is either outdated or inapplicable to WebAssemblies.

Thank you for any help, in advance.

Comment: close everything and try creating a new application from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after looking through a bunch of stuff I have determined that the problem was that I had no ConnectionString in appsettings.json.